# Z-Index issue in IE8

Tags: css

I can't seem to figure out why the tooltips go under the other links on the following page in IE8. It works great in IE9, FF, and Chrome

http://70.183.21.131/?page_id=87

Comment: As an aside, I'm seeing a `jQuery is undefined` error on that page.

Comment: The page loads with non matching browser and document mode. Who knows what render rules IE go by then? Make sure your pages renders in standards mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a problem that you are loading jquery.textshadow.js before jquery. jQuery is throwing an error that it is not loaded. Try moving the order of your scripts.

Comment: Make sure you are loading jquery.js FIRST, and VERY FIRST.